# Is two-body motion planar?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The two-body problem studies the motion of two bodies under the influence of their gravitational attraction.

Following the notation used in Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem,
let $x_1\in R^{3}$ and $x_2\in R^{3}$ be the positions of two bodies with masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ respectively. Let $r(t)=x_{1}(t)-x_{2}(t)$ be the difference vector from $m_{2}$ to $m_{1}$ and let $R(t)$ be the center of mass.

I understand the proof for that $r(t)$ is planar, i.e., $r(t)$ is perpendicular to some fixed vector (independent of t) for all $t$. And $R(t)$ is linear.

The Wikipedia page, as well as many textbooks, say that ``Two-body motion is planar".  Does it only mean $r(t)$ is planar? What about $x_{1}(t)$ and $x_{2}(t)$? Are they also planar?

(I understand that $x_{1}(t)-R(t)$ and $x_{2}(t)-R(t)$ are both planar, since they are just a scalar multiple of $r(t)$, but I don't see why $x_{1}(t)$ or $x_{2}(t)$ should be planar.)

Comment: [short answer] For a "classical" central force such as Newtonian gravity, the force on each body acts only along the line passing through both of them.  So there is no force component out of the plane defined by their velocity vectors, keeping their trajectories in a single plane.   (It requires a third external force to drive the trajectories out of that plane.)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner has most of it, also, angular momentum is conserved for a central force, so you can always define a plane using the angular momentum vector as the normal vector.

Comment: Dear RecklessReckoner, thanks for your explanation. Do you imply that the initial velocities must be parallel to the plane that initially contains the two bodies? Can't the initial velocities be arbitrarily chosen? For example, if initially $x_{1}(0)$ and $x_{2}(0)$ lies on the $xy$-plane, is it allowed to set the initial velocity $\dot{x}_{1}(0)$ to be $(0,0,1)$?

Comment: @Since1996 Two non-collinear vectors define a plane, so that is the orbital plane.  What I believe **Will Jagy** is describing is the situation where the center of mass is in uniform motion in a chosen reference frame, in which case, yes, the trajectories of the bodies will be "helical" about the center-of-mass' linear path.  I am using the center-of-mass frame, so I will apologize if that is confusing the issue.

Comment: @Silynn  I believe the conservation of orbital angular momentum is an equivalent expression of the situation, since the cross-products of the position and velocity vectors (in the center-of-mass frame) will be perpendicular to the orbital plane.

Comment: @Since1996 Looking at the (center-of-mass frame) diagram in the Wiki article you linked to (I presume you are referring to that), the initial position vectors alone do not determine the trajectories of the bodies; they only determine the magnitude and direction of force on each object.  The orbital plane and the shape and orientation of the trajectories will be determined by the initial _velocity_ vectors.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, thanks for your patient explanation!  I think I've found the real cause of my confusion --- that is, how two non-collinear vectors define a plane. Two noncollinear vectors define a family of planes (whose normal vector is the cross product of the two vectors), instead of a unique plane.  To define a unique plane, we need the normal vector of the plane, along with a point on the plane; in this case, the point is the center of the mass, and the normal vector is the angular momentum. So in the center-of-mass frame, the plane is unique. hope my understanding is correct now.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable description: in a frame where the center-of-mass is moving with constant velocity, the normal (angular momentum) vector is "parallel-transported".  So in such a reference frame, all of the instantaneous orbital planes are parallel to one another.